# Find Records from Different Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

**Requirement**

> Find and display all pilots (employee ID and name) who implemented
>   flights on the planes of 'Commuter' type and ‘Normal’ type.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
1st image is Plane_new table
2nd image is FlightI_new table
3rd image is Employee_new table
```

**Solution**

```
SELECT flightI_new.eid, employee_new.ename
FROM flightI_new
INNER JOIN employee_new ON flightI_new.eid = employee_new.eid
INNER JOIN plane_new ON flightI_new.pnum = plane_new.pnum
WHERE plane_new.ptype = 'Commuter' AND plane_new.ptype = 'Normal';
```

The code works with **OR**, but for some reason with AND i get "no rows returned".

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: your `AND` doesn't work here because you're looking at a single row. In a single row with your join 'commuter' and 'normal' are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AND` does not work because records cannot have both `ptype` on the same record. But you should be able to use something like this:

```
SELECT flightI_new.eid, employee_new.ename
FROM flightI_new
INNER JOIN employee_new 
    ON flightI_new.eid = employee_new.eid
INNER JOIN plane_new 
    ON flightI_new.pnum = plane_new.pnum
WHERE plane_new.ptype IN ('Commuter', 'Normal')
GROUP BY flightI_new.eid, employee_new.ename
HAVING count(distinct plane_new.ptype) = 2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a205/8)

Of you can use something like this:

```
SELECT distinct flightI_new."eid", employee_new."name"
FROM flightI_new
INNER JOIN employee_new 
    ON flightI_new."eid" = employee_new."eid"
INNER JOIN plane_new 
    ON flightI_new."pnum" = plane_new."pnum"
WHERE plane_new."ptype" = 'commuter'
  AND flightI_new."eid" IN (select flightI_new."eid"
                            FROM flightI_new
                            INNER JOIN employee_new 
                                ON flightI_new."eid" = employee_new."eid"
                            INNER JOIN plane_new 
                                ON flightI_new."pnum" = plane_new."pnum"
                            WHERE plane_new."ptype" = 'normal')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a205/13)

Comment: Good one: HAVING count(distinct plane_new.ptype) = 2;

Answer (score 0):

the wrong is here

```
      WHERE plane_new.ptype = 'Commuter' AND plane_new.ptype = 'Normal';
```

plane_new.ptype cant have two things ,computer and normal in your database, it must be one of them thats why u get no rows returned. 
so maybe you mean something else.
here in your WHERE statment u can use only `OR`. and they the rows returned are those who have `computer` and `normal`