# Select records counts from different table on the basis of join

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, count, multiple-tables

I want to get the count of records entered by a user in the different table. The schema of DB is:

```
+-----------------------+  
| Survey Master         |  
+----------------+------+   
| Field          | Key  |  
+----------------+------+  
| id             | PK   |  
| Username       |      |
| FamilyMasterId | FK   |
+----------------+------+

+------------+------+  
| Family Master     |  
+------------+------+   
| Field      | Key  |  
+------------+------+  
| id         | PK   |   
+------------+------+

+-----------------------+  
| Family Detail         |  
+----------------+------+   
| Field          | Key  |  
+----------------+------+  
| id             | PK   | 
| FamilyMasterId | FK   |   
+----------------+------+

+-----------------------+  
| Travel Master         |  
+----------------+------+   
| Field          | Key  |  
+----------------+------+  
| id             | PK   | 
| FamilyDetailId | FK   |   
+----------------+------+

+-----------------------+  
| Travel Detail         |  
+----------------+------+   
| Field          | Key  |  
+----------------+------+  
| id             | PK   | 
| TravelMasterId | FK   |   
+----------------+------+
```

I want to see the number of records created by each user in each table something like this:

```
  Username   SurveyMaster   FamilyMaster   FamilyDetail   TravelMaster   TravelDetail  
 ---------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- 
  User001    59             47             36             26             12            
  User002    88             76             64             42             25            
  User003    49             44             35             25             15            
  User004    77             69             55             45             37
```

After reviewing the following links:

1. [Find Records from Different Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460067/find-records-from-different-tables)
2. [Select count(*) from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606234/select-count-from-multiple-tables)
3. http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/join-different-tables-based-on-condition
4. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=5
5. [SQL: Combine Select count(*) from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279569/sql-combine-select-count-from-multiple-tables)

I was able to write this query but it gives the same records in all columns:

```
SELECT USERNAME, COUNT(USERNAME) SURVEYMASTER, COUNT(USERNAME) FAMILYMASTER, COUNT(USERNAME) FAMILYDETAIL, COUNT(USERNAME) TRAVELMASTER, COUNT(USERNAME) TRAVELDETAIL FROM 
((SELECT CREATEUSER USERNAME FROM SURVEYMASTER
) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT SM.CREATEUSER USERNAME FROM SURVEYMASTER SM
INNER JOIN FAMILYMASTER FM ON FM.ID = SM.FAMILYMASTERID
) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT SM.CREATEUSER USERNAME FROM SURVEYMASTER SM
INNER JOIN FAMILYMASTER FM ON FM.ID = SM.FAMILYMASTERID
INNER JOIN FAMILYDETAIL FD ON FM.ID = FD.FAMILYMASTERID
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT SM.CREATEUSER USERNAME FROM SURVEYMASTER SM
INNER JOIN FAMILYMASTER FM ON FM.ID = SM.FAMILYMASTERID
INNER JOIN FAMILYDETAIL FD ON FM.ID = FD.FAMILYMASTERID
INNER JOIN TRAVELMASTER TM ON FD.ID = TM.FAMILYDETAILID
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT SM.CREATEUSER USERNAME FROM SURVEYMASTER SM
INNER JOIN FAMILYMASTER FM ON FM.ID = SM.FAMILYMASTERID
INNER JOIN FAMILYDETAIL FD ON FM.ID = FD.FAMILYMASTERID
INNER JOIN TRAVELMASTER TM ON FD.ID = TM.FAMILYDETAILID
INNER JOIN TRAVELDETAIL TD ON TM.ID = TD.TRAVELMASTERID
)
) T
GROUP BY USERNAME
ORDER BY USERNAME
```

**EDIT**

Here is the relation description:

1. FamilyMasterId is the foreign key in SurveyMaster and FamilyDetail
   tables.
2. FamilyDetailId is the foreign key in TravelMaster table.
3. TravelMasterId is the foreign key in TravelDetail table.

Comment: If performance is not an issue, you can get each count using a separate sub-query. BTW, the relation between tables are not clear.

Comment: `to get the count of records entered by a user in the different table` **You need USERID** in each table e.g. created_by_userid

Comment: @Used_By_Already isn't there any way we can get the count though we the joins among all tables

Comment: @FLICKER I just added the description, do you think the column level query is going to be a good idea?

Comment: Yes. I think it would be more understandable and shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the perfect solution if we consider performance but it can give the desired result

```
SELECT  sm.Username ,
        COUNT(*) SurveyMaster ,
        COUNT(FamilyMasterId) FamilyMaster ,
        fd.FamilyDetail ,
        tm.TravelMaster ,
        td.TravelDetail
FROM    SurveyMaster sm
        JOIN ( SELECT   Username ,
                        COUNT(fd.id) FamilyDetail
               FROM     SurveyMaster sm
                        JOIN FamilyMaster fm ON sm.FamilyMasterId = fm.Id
                        JOIN FamilyDetail fd ON fm.id = fd.FamilyMasterId
               GROUP BY Username
             ) fd ON sm.Username = fd.Username
        JOIN ( SELECT   Username ,
                        COUNT(tm.id) TravelMaster
               FROM     SurveyMaster sm
                        JOIN FamilyMaster fm ON sm.FamilyMasterId = fm.Id
                        JOIN FamilyDetail fd ON fm.id = fd.FamilyMasterId
                        JOIN TravelMaster tm ON fd.Id = tm.FamilyDetailId
               GROUP BY Username
             ) tm ON sm.Username = tm.Username
        JOIN ( SELECT   Username ,
                        COUNT(td.id) TravelDetail
               FROM     SurveyMaster sm
                        JOIN FamilyMaster fm ON sm.FamilyMasterId = fm.Id
                        JOIN FamilyDetail fd ON fm.id = fd.FamilyMasterId
                        JOIN TravelMaster tm ON fd.Id = tm.FamilyDetailId
                        JOIN TravelDetail td ON tm.Id = td.TravelMasterId
               GROUP BY Username
             ) td ON sm.Username = td.Username
GROUP BY sm.Username ,
        fd.FamilyDetail ,
        tm.TravelMaster ,
        td.TravelDetail;
```

Comment: Thanks.. but what could be the better option if we talk about the performance as this is going to be the KPI for my project

Comment: The easiest solution is demoralisation i.e. adding user Id foreign key column in each table.

Comment: just for the knowledge, do you think adding userId to each table would be a best practice?. I am not an expert but I think we should reduce the data redundancy as much as we can.

Comment: There is a trade off between query execution time and storage. If you want queries to run faster, you might need to denormalize your tables. In that case, you will have data redundancy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540136/is-it-really-better-to-use-normalized-tables